# Finding a conditionally convergent series of functions in $C[0,1]$ with supremum norm w.r.t Faber-Schauder system.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, conditional-convergence

Let, \begin{align*}
        \alpha(x) &= 1 \\
        \beta(x) &= x\\
        s_{n,k}(x) &= \max\{1-|2(2^nx-k)-1|, 0\} \text{   for  } 0 \le n \text{ and } 0 \le k \le 2^{n}-1
    \end{align*}
We define the Faber-Schauder system
\begin{equation*}
    S := \{ \alpha, \beta \} \cup \{ s_{n,k} \}_{n \ge 0, 2^{n}-1 \ge k \ge 0 }
\end{equation*}

$s_{n,k}$ denotes the hat function supported on the interval $[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}]$ and whose peak is 1 and attained at $\frac{2k+1}{2^{n+1}}$. S is a basis for $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm. It is known that any basis for $C[0,1]$ is conditional. I am trying to find a concrete example of a series of functions which converges conditionally. My strategy is to use some sort of linear combinations of the basis functions i.e, $g_M = \sum_{n = 0}^{M} \sum_{k = 0}^{2^{n}-1} c_{n,k} s_{n,k}$. I will show that $g_M$  uniformly converges(show that it is uniformly cauchy). Then I show that $(-1)^n g_M$ doesn't uniformly converge(ideally goes to infinity). Vice versa is fine too, i.e, $(-1)^n g_M$ uniformly converges and $(-1)^n g_M$ doesn't uniformly converge. This shows that $g_M$(or $(-1)^n g_M$) is conditionally convergent. Or maybe, I could use another characterization of conditional convergence.

I tried couple of linear combinatons to construct $g_M$. For example, $g_M = \sum_{n = 0}^{M} s_{n,0}$ which didn't work.  Another example is constructed by firs considering interval $[0,1]$ and its corresponding function $t_0 = s_{0,0}$ then diveding it by half and taking the left part,$[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, which corresponds to $t_1 = s_{1,0}$ then divide half and take the right part, $[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]$, which correspond to $t_2 = s_{2,1}$ and so on. We always halve the current interval and alternate between taking the left part and right part with its corresponding function. $g_M = \sum_{n=0}^{M} t_n$.In this case, $g_M$ goes to infinity which is good. But I don't think $(-1)^ng_{M}$ uniformly converges.

I am looking forward for your ideas.

Comment: What does conditionnal convergence mean ? What is the $n$ in $(-1)^ng_M$, don't you mean $(-1)^Mg_M$ ? If $g_M$ converges toward $g$, $(-1)^Mg_M$ converges toward $0$ if $g = 0$, else it diverges.

Comment: @Klomanad Does $\frac12,\frac23, \frac34, \frac45,\cdots$ converge absolutely or conditionally? Does $\frac12,1,\frac23,1, \frac34,1, \frac45,1,\cdots$ converge absolutely or conditionally? **Could you please tell your answer to these two simple questions?** Once you have written your answer to these two questions, people including possibly yourself will be able to write a clear answer easily.

Comment: I think conditional convergence is a pretty agreed-upon concept.  A conditionally convergent sum has the property that the partial sums $ s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{f_k} $ converge to a limit in the space while the sum $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\|f_k\|} $ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$ 
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} s_{n,2^n-2}(x)\qquad \mathrm{for}\ n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots
$$
and the sum $ \sum f_n $ is conditionally convergent.   Let's prove it.  First, we have $ \sum \|f_n\| = \sum{1/n} =  \infty $ so we know it's not absolutely convergent.

What about conditional convergence?  Easy.  The functions $ f_n $ were chosen with disjoint supports.  So their pointwise convergence is trivial.  The limit of the sum is depicted with this cartoon which is clearly continuous (even at $ x = 1 $!)
[image: Cartoon of the limit function]

Comment: Why making it complicated? It is enough to use $\alpha(x)$ only.

Comment: @Apass.Jack aww damn now I feel dumb lol.